# Update field of first row where it's >0 until it reaches 0 than subtract from next row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to update the first row field that it's >0 and subtract from it until it reaches 0 then move on to the next row and keep subtracting from it?

Table:

| Column | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| First | 0 |
| Second | 5 |
| Third | 5 |

Amount to subtract = 9

Result:

| Column | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| First | 0 |
| Second | 0 |
| Third | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to get your job done. But it's will only run on MySQL 8.0 and higher.

```
 create table mytable (Columns varchar(50),Amount int);
 insert into mytable values('First',    0);
 insert into mytable values('Second',   5);
 insert into mytable values('Third',    5);
```

Query:

```
 with recursive
 cte as
 (
   select Columns,amount,row_number()over(order by Columns) rn from mytable
 )
 , cte2 as
 (
  select Columns, (case when amount0 then (case when amount9 then amount-9 else 0 end) else 0 end)amount,
  (case when amount0 then (case when amount9 then 0 else 9-amount end) else 9 end)remainingamount,rn
  from cte where rn=1
  union all
  select cte.Columns,(case when cte.amount0 then (case when cte.amountremainingamount then cte.amount-remainingamount else 0 end)else 0 end)amount
  ,(case when cte.amount0 then (case when cte.amountremainingamount then 0 else remainingamount-cte.amount end) else 0 end)remainingamount ,cte.rn
  from  cte inner join cte2 on cte2.rn=cte.rn-1
 )
 select columns, amount from cte2
```

Output:

| columns | amount |
| --- | --- |
| First | 0 |
| Second | 0 |
| Third | 1 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf255c39d09c25bef8fed7013151253a)*

Answer (score 0):

Even the solution by @Kazi is perfect, maybe this is a simplified version of the query, using cols as rownumbers

```
with recursive
data as (
  select 1 as col, 0 as amount union all
  select 2,5 union all
  select 3,5
),
cte as (
  -- anchor member
  select
    col, 
    amount, 
    9 as substract
  from data
  where col = 1
  union all
  -- recursive member
  select 
    data.col,
    case when (data.amount - cte.substract) < 0 then 0 else data.amount - cte.substract end,
    case when (cte.substract - data.amount) < 0 then 0 else cte.substract - data.amount end
  from data
    join cte
      on data.col = cte.col + 1
)
select * from cte
```

you can test on this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d4c9bb82356d8189dec59db9f695c7cf).

This is the only way to solve this kind of queries using "pure" sql, but the performance of these queries working with big amounts of data is not usually good.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 9 >= running_amount then 0
             when 9 >= running_amount - amount then running_amount - 9
             else amount
        end) as remainder
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (order by column) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28148e8e9664cebc7b49d0265d63e4bd) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This assumes that the first column actually represents the ordering of the rows.

Comment: with the sample data there is no doubt your query works well, but if the data had an extra row with an amount = 5, your query would stop to do the right job.

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . It works fine in that case:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f78b1494e197e7dd89c31f596ffe8ac.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, as far as I have understood the question, when the 9 is "exhausted", it should return 0, not 5. The 9 is a value which changes in each iteration with rows, not a fixed one. (As far as I understand the question...). You can see the behaviour I mean on this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b7165e859ca623b817c0761f32d7aabc

Comment: Maybe with some `lag` function you could do the job, but I don't know if they are allowed in mysql (and I have to recognize I love recursive cte, they are soooo weird )

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . I think you misunderstand the question.  Recursive CTEs are great.  However, other methods often have better -- much better -- performance so they should be used judiciously.